# How do i get the last time windows succesfully updated?

Tags: c++, windows-update

I am attempting to get a date and time of the last time Windows updated on a machine through C++. I have been successfully able to do it through powershell like so:
`string LastUpdate = exec("powershell.exe $(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate");`

However due to it being run through powershell, it kind of delays the whole rest of the program, so i was wondering if there is any easy ways to do it through C++?

Comment: Use [the C++ version of the same interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iautomaticupdates).

Comment: @RaymondChen I’ve attempted to do so, but i only got a response that contained some numbers. Would you be so kind to provide me some example code?

Comment: You will get a `VT_DATE`, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/35c9bf2d-b8e8-4d7d-a50f-367da0d99fce). You can use [VariantTimeToSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varianttimetosystemtime) to convert to `SYSTEMTIME`.